# limit concurrent sessions to Apache tomcat web application

Tags: tomcat, concurrency, connection

I am using a web application based on Apache Tomcat. How can I limit the number of concurrent connections to this application in order to prevent more than a specific number of users from accessing it?

I am not a programmer, so if there is a way without a code it will be perfect.

Comment: HTTP is stateless, limit concurrent connections will not limit the number of users. You can decrease the maxThreads to let tomcat to handle less concurrent requests, but this is probably not what you want. Limiting the number of concurrent users should be at the application level

Answer (score 2):

To limit the number of *simultaneous connections*, modify your `<Connector>` configuration in `conf/server.xml`:

```
<Connector ...
  maxConnections="10"
  />
```

You can set that value to almost anything. But that doesn't limit the number of users that can "use" the system at any given time. If you are using HTTP sessions to track "logged-in users", then you can limit the number of simultaneous sessions by modifying your application's `META-INF/context.xml` file to include:

```
<Manager ...
  maxActiveSessions="10"
  />
```

You can set that to just about anything you want.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html

Comment: Is there any way to do this per user?  That is, instead of the max number of sessions for the server, specify the max number of sessions per user?

Comment: @rjcarr There is nothing in the servlet specification or any existing application server that will handle this for you. You would have to implement it yourself at the application-level.